# Azure cant login from github actions

Tags: github-actions, azure-cli

Im trying to deploy from github actions using the following yml:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2

        - name: "Login via Azure CLI"
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            client-id: GUID
            tenant-id: GUID
            subscription-id: GUID
```

but im getting the error: `Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner.`

If i change to `creds` with the json, i get that the credentials are incorrect.

This is how i build the json:

`az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "{ADD YOU NAMEW HERE}" --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{subscriptionId} --sdk-auth`

thanks

Comment: Is the error message from the login step or from your build step?

Comment: @rethab from the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

If your project is ready on the GitHub make sure to update the same in your local environment the `example.yml` file and push them. After creation of credentials using [**`az ad sp create-for-rbac`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) . Store those value  into a secret file and pass this as variable in the `example.yml` file and try to execute as below.

```
 File: .github/workflows/workflow.yml

  on: [push]

name: AzureLoginSample

jobs:

  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    
    - run: |
        az webapp list --query "[?state=='Running']"
```

*For more information Please refer this* **GitHub MarketPlace**|[***GitHub Actions for deploying to Azure***](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-login#configure-a-service-principal-with-a-secret) and this **TechCommunity Blog**|[***How to login to Azure with GitHub Actions***](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/how-to-login-to-azure-with-github-actions/ba-p/3573050) by @*Alfredo Deza*.

Comment: I see that you are a Microsoft employee - it is actually not working in: https://github.com/nektos/act and not in github actions it self. I think it is for Azure benefit to make it work there. it is very popular. BTW I gave up on Azure container apps... very hard to deploy dapr apps and lack of community. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you run this command it should work

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "app-test-1" --role contributor \
                        --scopes /subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group \
                        --sdk-auth
```

it will output a json payload, put that json payload in the your repo's secret and then call it in your yaml file

```
- uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding contributor role assignment to the app registration I was adding federated credentials to. My error specifically said No subscriptions found for ...
[image]

1. Navigate to the subscription you'd like to deploy to.
2. In the Access control (IAM) blade press Add -> Role Assignment.
   [image]
3. For my project I chose Contributor (in Privileged administrator roles), but choose whatever role you think the pipeline would need access to.
4. Add the app in the Members section. You can search for the name of the app with the + Select members button. Then Review + assign.
5. Retry pipeline step:
   [image]